# Cannot scroll in UIWebView in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, ios-simulator

I created a webview programmatically and I am unable to enable scrolling in this view.

How do I enable scrolling?

```
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40, 325, 1000)];
    webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;     
    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.view insertSubview:webView atIndex:0];
```

**Thanks In Advance !**

Comment: Ummm, if you have the content set to scale & fit (e.g. "`UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`"), wouldn't the whole page fit on screen and not scroll?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann..I tried disabling "UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit" but I still cannot scroll. webView just bounces

Comment: @skokal01 that means that all the content is visible on the screen so there is nothing to scroll to

Comment: @Otium...I guarantee that there is lot of content. BTW I changed my code to create UIWebView from interface builder and now I am able to scroll perfectly. I am wondering what I have missed in my code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To enable scrolling,

```
webview.scrollView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
```

and instead of writing this,

```
webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

write this,

```
webview.scalesPageToFit = TRUE;
```

Comment: @krunal...It didnot work. Now my html page is shrunk to 1/4th size of the screen and I can't even zoom in :(

Comment: Please see the screenshot at [UIWebView Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/EGQYx.png)

Comment: size of your web view is not proper.. chk that, it should be `webview.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 770, 960);`

Comment: @krunal..nope it still doesn't scroll.

Comment: try this, `webview.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);` and remove this line `webview.scalesPageToFit = TRUE;` & thn tell me what happens..

Comment: @Krunal...After resizing the UIWebView correctly it worked    `UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;` BTW if I set webView.scalesPageToFit, page shrinks to 1/4th of the screen size.

Comment: @krunal...I was about to mark the question as answered. anyways thx

Comment: I had this same problem and in my case I was trying to add the `UIWebView` to a parent `UIView` that was smaller than my webView. I found this easily by setting the borderWidth on the parent view.

Comment: I think you mean YES not TRUE. This is objective c! :)

Answer (score 0):

These are the possible solutions.

i) You webview may be large in size than you expected or your content is lesser than the webview size.

2) Implement following method.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView)
{
    appDelegate.hideLoadingView()

    let res: NSString = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.offsetHeight;")!
    let h: CGFloat = CGFloat(res.integerValue)
    agreementContentView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(webView.frame.size.width, h + 50); // Offset if required
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Removing from Interface Builder and adding via code did for me. For some reason in IB it wasn't scrolling.

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 50)];
[self.view addSubview: webView];
```