# UIWebView not scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios

I am creating a UIWebView that is being added as a subview to a UIView however I am unable to get the WebView to scroll. Any advice is appreciated.

```
- (UIWebView *) mainText
{
    UIWebView *view = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    view.frame = CGRectMake(8, 130, 275, 185);
    [view loadHTMLString:@"<font color=\"blue\">Hello Worldcut features is an option we skip the admin site entirely and just have josh do the AP then I cut out all the filters and I can cut out all the we don't need the social aspect on this quite yet l the filters and I can cut out all the we don't need the social aspect on this quite yetl the filters and I can cut out all the we don't need the social aspect on this quite yetl the filters and I can cut out all the we don't need the social aspect on this quite yetl the filters and I can cut out all the we don't need the social aspect on this quite yetl the filters and I can cut out all the we don't need the social aspect on this quite yetl the filters and I can cut out all the  </font>" baseURL:nil];

    return view;
}
```

Comment: its scrolling in my code, I have just copy and paste in my view. ALso make sure to check parent User interaction is enabled.

Comment: the last part of the accepted answer is what i believe you need to look into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875971/cannot-scroll-in-uiwebview-in-ios

Comment: Please search before posting.

Comment: Yes I did search and I did come across the link Clint provided, however the solution did not work in my case.  Mayank, good to know it's working for you. I will keep looking around to see if something else is going on then.

Comment: out of curiosity, how can OP close this question when the answer is given as a comment? (or should I search faq before asking :| )

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my problem was I was outside of my parent `UIView`. I discovered this once I put a border around the `UIView` I was attempting to add it to and that's how I saw the problem.